# Idiomatic way to do "find_package and download & build a fallback if not found"

Tags: cmake, idioms, build-dependencies, find-package, fetchcontent

I have a CMake project which requires package `foo`, with a certain version range.

Now, I don't want to force my own foo tarball into the project, nor always download a release from the Internet, i.e. I want to use `find_package()`. I also like the aesthetics of always doing that.

At the same time, if `find_package()` fails, I *do* want to fallback to something, let's say the equivalent of a FetchContent_declare with some parameters I provide (e.g. building from a tarball I've bundled or downloading it from the web).

What is the idiomatic way to set-up this "find_package with fallback"?

Notes:

- I've noticed that there is some sort of hooking in `find_package()` which allows us to use `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE` in `FetchContent_declare()`, so maybe that can be used to implement the fallback I'm after
- Assume a CMake version as high as you like

Comment: You probably are looking for `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS` parameter of `FetchContent_Declare`. When content is created with that parameter, calling `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` firstly executes `find_package`. If `find_package` succeed, nothing else is performed. Otherwise content is downloaded and configured as usual.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Ah, but I would like it the other way around: I want my "main" CMakeLists.txt to say `find_package(foo)`, not `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`. That way, if I cut out my auxiliary CMake inclusion/subdir which sets everything up, I have a valid, declarative, CMakeLists.txt which just expects the packages magically.

Comment: The CMake idiomatic **name** for functionality "use existed package, otherwise download it" is `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`.  And CMake provides good helpers for that functionality. Why do you insist on **other name** (`find_package`) for that functionality? Well, you may implement the functionality for the name `find_package` too: just create `FindFoo.cmake` and add needed logic to it. But why reinvent the wheel, if the functionality is already implemented under the proper name?